# кастомный аллокатор под кучу c++

Tags: c++, c++11, память

Добрый день! Пронаследовал класс аллокатора для использования HeapAlloc в качестве источника выделяемой памяти. Проблема заключается в следующем: последующие, начиная со второго, выделения памяти завершаются исключением типа access violatuion. Вот код:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
template<class T>
class HeapAllocator
{
private :
    HANDLE hHeap;
    size_t size;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using Traits = std::allocator_traits<HeapAllocator<T>>;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T *;
    using reference = T &;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    T * allocate(std::size_t n);
    pointer address(reference value) const { return  &value; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference value) const { return &value; }
    void deallocate(T * p, std::size_t n);
    size_type max_size() const  { return             std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() / sizeof(T); }
    template<class U, class... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) { std::allocator<T>().construct(p,         std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    template<class U>
    void destroy(U* p) { std::allocator<T>().destroy(p); }
    HeapAllocator();
    ~HeapAllocator();
    template<class U>
    struct rebind 
    { 
        using other = HeapAllocator<U>;
    };
    template<class U>
    HeapAllocator(const HeapAllocator<U> & other) {}
};
template<class T>
HeapAllocator<T>::HeapAllocator()
{
    hHeap = HeapCreate(HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE|
               HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE,
                1024, 0);
}
template<class T>
HeapAllocator<T>::~HeapAllocator()
{
    HeapDestroy(hHeap);
}
template<class T1, class T2>
bool operator==(const HeapAllocator<T1> &, const HeapAllocator<T2> &)         throw()
{
    return true;
}
template <class T1, class T2>
bool operator!=(const HeapAllocator<T1>&,
const HeapAllocator<T2>&) throw() {
    return false;
}
template<class T>
T * HeapAllocator<T>::allocate(std::size_t n)
{
    void *p = nullptr;
     p = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(T) * n);
    if (p == nullptr)
    std::cerr << GetLastError() << '\n';
    return reinterpret_cast<T *>(p);
}
template<class T>
void HeapAllocator<T>::deallocate(T *p, size_t n)
{
    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, p);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в детали... при копировании или присвоении `hHeap` становится недействительным, ибо в деструкторе вызывается `HeapDestroy(hHeap);`.

При любом уничтожении любой копии получается масса неприятностей.

Comment: вы правы, спасибо.)